# What is the (standardized) weight of a 3.5 inch floppy disk?

Tags: floppy-disk, storage

What is the weight of a 3.5 inch floppy disk and was the weight ever standardized?

[image: a bunch of 3.5inch floppy disks]

Comment: Why do you think that the mass might be standardised, especially of the whole package?  I could understand some standardisation for the disk itself (or more specifically its moment of inertia about the spindle axis), but even that seems unlikely, as drives will just take longer to spin up heavier disks than lighter ones.  It's actually a differentiating feature (build quality against speed against cost) of different brands.

Comment: What’s more, there’s quite a lot of scope for variation: the rotating disk itself probably won’t vary much, but the rigid package can, the larger disk at the centre also can, metal shutters weigh more than plastic shutters, different types of spring can be used, and some disks even had protective coating inside the rigid package which would add (a little) weight.

Comment: Some disks hold more data than others.  Therefore it is logical to conclude that Double Density disks must weigh more than Single Density disks, right?  ;^)

Comment: @Geo... It wouldn't actually surprise me that much if ED disks weighed more due to the different coating used for those, to support perpendicular recording.

Comment: Pedantic answer: there isn't a standard weight of *3½ inch* disks, because there is no such thing standardised. The standard specifies the physical size of the disk as 90 mm.

Comment: At least the ECMA-100 and ECMA-125 standards *do not* define a weight for 90 mm cartridges.

Comment: Depends:  European or African?

Comment: Not sure if it's me or you being weird here, but AFAIK there is no such thing as a "3.5-inch floppy disk". Have you tried to bend one? They're not "floppy"! You get a 3.5-inch stiffy disk, and a 5.25-inch floppy disk

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Laden or unladen? (...thinks... is a newly formatted disk lighter than a full disk?)

Comment: @ReversedEngineer, That depends on whether you think that "disk" refers to the circular piece of coated mylar film that is contained within the assembly, or whether you think it refers to the entire assembly. The mylar film certainly is floppy (Don't ask me how I know!)

Comment: @SolomonSlow Good point! Now I have to ask: How do you know that the mylar film inside a 3.5" stiffy is floppy?

Comment: @SolomonSlow - indeed.  It's odd to complain that the package is not floppy while ignoring that it's not a disc.

Comment: @SolomonSlow If we wanted to be super pedantic we could argue that's the reason it's called a "disk" and not a "disc". Really though, I agree with you. In North America at least, only the non-technical crowd would call a 3.5" disk anything but a "floppy", typically by erroneously (and confusingly) referring to it as a "hard disk".

Comment: We could also talk about why people talk about "hard drives".  [Drives](http://www.columbia.edu/cu/computinghistory/rp04.html) and [disks](https://rapc-association.org.uk/Assets/User/433-disk_pack.jpg) are clearly different!  As, in fact, anyone who's used a floppy should know.

Comment: Are you talking unladen? European or African? ;)

Comment: @Geo... Actually, "single-density" and "double-density" are the exact same media: it's the controller and driver software that determines whether data are recorded in a single- or double-density format. So a double-density disk (or diskette, if smaller than 8") weighs twice as much as a single-density disk only _after_ it's been formatted as double-density. Thus, if you need to transport media (but not their data) somewhere, it's worth reformatting them as single-density or bulk-erasing them to reduce their weight.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**The short answer / TLDR:** One 3.5-inch floppy disk weighs between 15 - 25 grams. The average (mean) weight of one 3.5-inch floppy disk is 18 grams, the median is 17 gram. *Of that weight 75% is estimated to consist of the plastic housing and paper ring only, 14% for a metal shutter and 11% for the hub.*

---

### The data

Below you'll find the data (in semicolon CSV format) as requested in the comments. It contains the brand and production country if available, whether the disk contained a paper label and what type of disk 3.5-inch disk it was (HD or DD).

```
Brand;ProductionCountry;LabelPasted;HD/DD;Grams
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;19
Verbatim;Unknown;No;HD;18
Unknown;Germany;Yes;HD;20
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;21
Unknown;Germany;Yes;DD;21
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;16
MCN;Unknown;Yes;DD;21
BASF;Unknown;Yes;HD;19
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Unknown;Japan;No;HD;21
Unknown;Germany;Yes;HD;19
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;19
Unknown;Germany;Yes;HD;25
Unknown;Germany;Yes;HD;21
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Unknown;Germany;Yes;HD;20
3M;Unknown;No;HD;21
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;20
Unknown;Germany;Yes;DD;21
Unknown;Germany;Yes;DD;21
3M;Unknown;Yes;DD;20
3M;Unknown;Yes;DD;22
3M;Unknown;Yes;DD;22
3M;Unknown;Yes;DD;22
3M;Unknown;Yes;DD;22
3M;Unknown;Yes;DD;22
3M;Unknown;Yes;DD;22
3M;Unknown;Yes;DD;23
Unknown;Germany;Yes;DD;21
Unknown;Germany;Yes;DD;21
Unknown;Germany;Yes;DD;20
Maxell;Japan;Yes;DD;21
Maxell;Japan;Yes;DD;22
Maxell;Japan;Yes;DD;21
Fujifilm;Germany;Yes;DD;19
Nashua;Japan;Yes;DD;21
Nashua;Japan;Yes;DD;22
Nashua;Japan;Yes;DD;21
Nashua;Japan;Yes;DD;22
Nashua;Japan;Yes;DD;21
Nashua;Japan;Yes;DD;22
Unknown;U.S.A.;No;DD;21
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;DD;21
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;DD;22
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;DD;21
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;DD;22
MCN;Unknown;Yes;DD;21
MCN;Unknown;Yes;DD;20
INMAC;Unknown;Yes;DD;21
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;DD;21
BASF;Unknown;Yes;DD;23
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;DD;21
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;DD;22
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;DD;22
Unknown;Germany;Yes;DD;19
Unknown;E.C.;Yes;DD;17
3M;Unknown;No;HD;21
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;21
Unknown;E.C.;No;HD;17
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;20
Unknown;E.C.;No;HD;20
Unknown;Germany;No;HD;17
Unknown;Germany;No;HD;17
Unknown;Germany;No;HD;17
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;18
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;20
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;21
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;17
Unknown;Germany;No;HD;17
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;18
Unknown;E.C.;No;HD;17
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;17
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;19
Unknown;E.C.;No;HD;17
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;17
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;17
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;17
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;19
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;19
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;20
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;20
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;19
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;20
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;19
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;19
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;20
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;18
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;20
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;20
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;19
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;21
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;19
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;20
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;18
Unknown;Japan;No;HD;21
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;20
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;20
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;22
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;19
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;19
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;20
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;19
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;21
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;20
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;20
Unknown;Japan;No;HD;20
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;21
Imation;Unknown;No;HD;17
Imation;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
Imation;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
Imation;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Imation;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
Imation;U.S.A.;No;HD;16
Imation;U.S.A.;No;HD;16
Imation;U.S.A.;No;HD;16
Imation;U.S.A.;Yes;HD;18
Imation;U.S.A.;Yes;HD;17
Imation;U.S.A.;Yes;HD;17
Imation;U.S.A.;Yes;HD;16
Imation;U.S.A.;Yes;HD;16
Imation;Unknown;No;HD;16
Imation;Unknown;No;HD;16
Imation;U.S.A.;Yes;HD;17
Imation;U.S.A.;No;HD;16
Imation;U.S.A.;Yes;HD;18
Imation;U.S.A.;No;HD;18
Imation;U.S.A.;Yes;HD;17
Imation;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Imation;Unknown;No;HD;16
Imation;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
3M;Unknown;Yes;HD;20
3M;Unknown;Yes;HD;21
3M;Unknown;Yes;HD;20
3M;Unknown;Yes;HD;21
3M;Unknown;Yes;HD;20
3M;Unknown;Yes;HD;20
3M;Unknown;Yes;HD;21
3M;Unknown;Yes;HD;20
3M;Unknown;Yes;HD;21
3M;Unknown;Yes;HD;21
3M;Unknown;Yes;HD;20
3M;Unknown;Yes;HD;21
3M;Unknown;Yes;HD;21
3M;Unknown;Yes;HD;20
3M;Unknown;Yes;HD;19
3M;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
3M;Unknown;Yes;HD;19
Imation;U.S.A.;No;HD;16
Imation;U.S.A.;Yes;HD;17
Imation;U.S.A.;Yes;HD;17
Imation;U.S.A.;Yes;HD;18
Imation;U.S.A.;Yes;HD;17
Imation;Unknown;No;HD;18
Imation;Unknown;No;HD;18
Imation;Unknown;No;HD;18
Imation;Unknown;No;HD;18
Imation;Unknown;No;HD;17
Sony;Unknown;No;HD;17
Sony;Unknown;No;HD;17
Sony;Unknown;No;HD;18
Sony;Unknown;No;HD;18
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;19
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;19
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;19
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;19
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;20
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;19
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;19
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;19
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;19
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;19
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;19
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;19
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;19
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;19
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;23
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;19
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
TDK;Unknown;No;HD;20
TDK;Unknown;No;HD;21
TDK;Unknown;No;HD;21
TDK;Unknown;Yes;HD;22
TDK;U.S.A.;Yes;HD;22
TDK;U.S.A.;Yes;HD;21
TDK;U.S.A.;Yes;HD;22
TDK;U.S.A.;Yes;HD;22
TDK;U.S.A.;Yes;HD;21
TDK;U.S.A.;Yes;HD;21
TDK;U.S.A.;Yes;HD;22
TDK;U.S.A.;Yes;HD;22
TDK;Unknown;No;HD;16
TDK;Unknown;Yes;HD;15
TDK;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
TDK;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
TDK;Unknown;Yes;HD;15
TDK;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
TDK;Unknown;Yes;HD;15
TDK;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
TDK;Unknown;Yes;HD;15
TDK;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
TDK;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
TDK;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
TDK;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
TDK;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
Dixons;E.C.;No;HD;17
Dixons;E.C.;No;HD;17
Dixons;E.C.;No;HD;16
Dixons;E.C.;No;HD;16
Dixons;E.C.;No;HD;16
Dixons;E.C.;No;HD;16
Dixons;E.C.;No;HD;16
Dixons;E.C.;No;HD;16
Dixons;E.C.;No;HD;16
Dixons;E.C.;No;HD;16
Dixons;E.C.;No;HD;16
Dixons;E.C.;No;HD;16
Dixons;E.C.;No;HD;16
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
Dixons;E.C.;Yes;HD;17
Dixons;E.C.;Yes;HD;17
Dixons;E.C.;Yes;HD;17
Dixons;E.C.;Yes;HD;17
Dixons;E.C.;Yes;HD;18
Dixons;E.C.;Yes;HD;17
Dixons;E.C.;Yes;HD;16
Dixons;E.C.;Yes;HD;17
Dixons;E.C.;Yes;HD;16
Dixons;E.C.;Yes;HD;16
Dixons;E.C.;Yes;HD;16
Dixons;E.C.;Yes;HD;17
Dixons;E.C.;Yes;HD;16
Dixons;E.C.;Yes;HD;16
Dixons;E.C.;Yes;HD;16
Dixons;E.C.;Yes;HD;16
Dixons;E.C.;Yes;HD;17
Dixons;E.C.;Yes;HD;16
Dixons;E.C.;Yes;HD;17
Dixons;E.C.;Yes;HD;16
Dixons;E.C.;Yes;HD;16
Dixons;E.C.;Yes;HD;17
MCN;Japan;Yes;HD;21
MCN;Japan;Yes;HD;21
MCN;Japan;Yes;HD;21
MCN;Japan;Yes;HD;21
MCN;Japan;Yes;HD;21
TDK;E.C.;Yes;HD;16
TDK;E.C.;Yes;HD;16
TDK;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
TDK;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
TDK;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
TDK;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
TDK;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
TDK;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
TDK;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
TDK;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
TDK;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
TDK;E.C.;No;HD;17
TDK;E.C.;No;HD;17
TDK;E.C.;No;HD;17
TDK;E.C.;No;HD;16
TDK;E.C.;No;HD;15
TDK;E.C.;No;HD;16
TDK;E.C.;No;HD;16
TDK;E.C.;No;HD;15
TDK;E.C.;No;HD;15
TDK;E.C.;No;HD;16
TDK;E.C.;No;HD;16
TDK;E.C.;No;HD;16
TDK;E.C.;No;HD;16
TDK;E.C.;No;HD;16
TDK;E.C.;No;HD;16
TDK;E.C.;No;HD;16
TDK;E.C.;No;HD;16
Maxell;England;Yes;HD;15
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;20
BASF;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
IBM;Japan;Yes;HD;20
Mitsubishi;Japan;Yes;HD;21
Mitsubishi;Japan;Yes;HD;20
Mitsubishi;Japan;Yes;HD;21
Unknown;Japan;Yes;HD;21
Fujifilm;Germany;Yes;HD;17
Fujifilm;Germany;Yes;HD;16
Fujifilm;Germany;Yes;HD;17
Fujifilm;Germany;Yes;HD;17
Fujifilm;Germany;Yes;HD;17
Fujifilm;Germany;Yes;HD;17
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;19
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;19
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;20
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;16
Unknown;E.C.;No;HD;17
Unknown;E.C.;No;HD;16
Unknown;E.C.;No;HD;16
Unknown;E.C.;No;HD;16
Unknown;E.C.;No;HD;17
Unknown;England;Yes;HD;18
Unknown;Germany;Yes;HD;16
Unknown;Germany;Yes;HD;16
Unknown;E.C.;Yes;HD;17
Unknown;E.C.;Yes;HD;17
Unknown;E.C.;Yes;HD;17
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;20
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;21
3M;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
3M;Unknown;No;HD;17
BASF;Unknown;No;HD;17
BASF;Unknown;No;HD;17
BASF;Unknown;No;HD;16
BASF;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
BASF;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
BASF;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
BASF;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
HEMA;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
HEMA;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
HEMA;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
HEMA;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
HEMA;Unknown;No;HD;16
HEMA;Unknown;No;HD;16
HEMA;Unknown;No;HD;17
Verbatim;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Verbatim;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Verbatim;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Verbatim;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Verbatim;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Verbatim;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Verbatim;Unknown;Yes;HD;19
Fujifilm;Germany;Yes;HD;16
Fujifilm;Germany;No;HD;15
Fujifilm;Germany;No;HD;16
Fujifilm;Germany;No;HD;15
Fujifilm;Germany;No;HD;16
Fujifilm;Germany;No;HD;15
Fujifilm;Germany;No;HD;16
Fujifilm;Germany;No;HD;16
Fujifilm;Germany;No;HD;15
Imation;Unknown;No;HD;16
Imation;Unknown;No;HD;17
Imation;Unknown;No;HD;16
Imation;Unknown;No;HD;15
Imation;Unknown;No;HD;16
Imation;Unknown;No;HD;15
Imation;Unknown;No;HD;16
Imation;Unknown;No;HD;16
Imation;Unknown;No;HD;16
Sony;Unknown;No;HD;17
Sony;Unknown;No;HD;16
Sony;Unknown;No;HD;16
Sony;Unknown;No;HD;16
Sony;Unknown;No;HD;17
Sony;Unknown;No;HD;17
Sony;Unknown;No;HD;16
Sony;Unknown;No;HD;16
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
Sony;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
Unknown;E.C.;No;HD;18
Unknown;E.C.;No;HD;18
Unknown;E.C.;No;HD;18
Unknown;E.C.;No;HD;18
Unknown;E.C.;No;HD;18
Unknown;Unknown;No;HD;16
Unknown;Germany;Yes;HD;16
Unknown;Germany;Yes;HD;16
Unknown;Germany;Yes;HD;16
Unknown;Germany;Yes;HD;16
Unknown;Germany;Yes;HD;15
Unknown;E.C.;Yes;HD;16
Unknown;E.C.;Yes;HD;16
Unknown;E.C.;Yes;HD;16
Unknown;E.C.;Yes;HD;16
Unknown;E.C.;Yes;HD;16
Unknown;E.C.;Yes;HD;17
Unknown;E.C.;Yes;HD;16
Unknown;E.C.;Yes;HD;16
Unknown;E.C.;Yes;HD;17
Unknown;E.C.;Yes;HD;15
Unknown;E.C.;Yes;HD;15
Unknown;E.C.;Yes;HD;15
Unknown;E.C.;Yes;HD;16
Unknown;E.C.;Yes;HD;16
Unknown;E.C.;Yes;HD;16
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;19
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;20
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;20
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;20
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;20
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;16
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;19
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;19
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;18
Unknown;Unknown;Yes;HD;17
```

Of the measured set 64% contained a printed label and 36% did not. 91% of the set was of the type HD and 9% of the type DD. As requested the standard deviation is 2.1.

#### Weight distribution per part

I've measured the weight of a few independent parts of floppy disks too. Those measurements included 5 metal hubs, 8 aluminium shutters and 4 plastic housings incl. the paper ring. The magnetic disk and spring (out of experience) weigh almost nothing.*

```
11% Metal hub                    5x total 11g    per piece  2.20g
14% Aluminium shutter            8x total 22g    per piece  2.75g
75% Housing incl. paper ring     4x total 60g    per piece 15.00g
Totals                                    93g    per piece 19.95g
```

[image: Independent floppy parts]

Roughly 75% of the weight consist of the plastic housing and paper ring, 14% shutter and 11% hub. As mentioned other parts (spring, magnetic disk, write protect tab, label) were not measured but are probably negligible.

### Method used

I measured the weight of 431 floppy disks (3.5-inch) from several brands such as 3M, BASF, Dixons, Fujifilm, HEMA, IBM, Imation, INMAC, Maxell, MCN,  Mitsubishi, Nashua, Sony, TDK, Verbatim and types (DD/HD) using below shown kitchen scale and set to 0 before measuring per floppy.

[image: Electronic digital kitchen scale CM-103/10672Z]

### Standardization

Regarding the standardization: I could not find any information that indicates there has been a standardized weight for 3.5-inch floppy disks.

Comment: Also it wouldn't have made too much sense to standardize the weight as an additional limit. These standards are (mostly) about cross-compatibility, and a couple grams more or less (or even double the weight) would hardly hurt the readers

Comment: A customer might expect a "double density" disk of the same size to be twice as heavy.

Comment: @JDługosz even more with compressed files are stored :)

Comment: 1.61 µg/bit (I expected them to be heavier) ;)

Comment: Do you still have the raw data?  I'm interested in getting a copy of it.

Comment: @tofro You should include that you used 1440 KiB for that calculation. Some systems stored more than that, and then there were EDs, flopticals, superdisks, ...

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I am not sure what that data could be useful for but I've changed the answer and added the raw data for you.

Comment: I wanted to know the standard deviation, but it seems that I won't be able to get it because some of the data were grouped.  But thanks anyway.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I believe the standard deviation is 2.1. I've remeasured and updates the answer and dataset. If you perform additional fancy data analysis on it, feel free to share it here.

Comment: @Zac67 I tend to be pretty precise when I'm *not* joking;)

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Thanks for the bounty. It's appreciated :).

Comment: @BobOrtiz Your percentages are off by an order of magnitude. 2.2 grams is not 1% of 22 grams or whatever ballpark weight you were thinking of. It's 10%, and it's 13% of the median weight of 17 grams. So your 96% figure is off by at least 12 points.

Comment: @LearningFast You are right. My mistake. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity - why did you have 431 different brands of floppies at hand for this?!

Comment: This answer deserves an *Extreme Dedication to the Bit* award, if such a thing could exist.. Epic work, @BobOrtiz! A more pedantic person than me might ask about the calibration certificates of your scale, validity and traceability thereof, but I'm not going there

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen fair question. I measured 431 floppy disks from **several** brands (like those mentioned). So not floppies from "431 different brands". I have a lot of floppies laying around as part of a hobby project I'm working on, I bought a bunch of mostly used disks on Ebay-like sites for that.

Answer (score 2):

I can't add much to Bob Ortiz's answer, but a small sample of 5 each HD floppies (unlabelled) from three different brands measured on a jeweller's scale resulted in:

```
Mean              17.2
Median            17.4
Min               16.0
Max               17.6
```

The measured data are as follows:

```
Brand               ProductionCountry   LabelPasted HD/DD     Grams
Memorex             China               No          HD        17.6
Memorex             China               No          HD        17.4
Memorex             China               No          HD        17.6
Memorex             China               No          HD        17.6
Memorex             China               No          HD        17.6
Fujifilm (red)      Malaysia            No          HD        16.0
Fujifilm (orange)   Malaysia            No          HD        16.2
Fujifilm (yellow)   Malaysia            No          HD        16.7
Fujifilm (green)    Malaysia            No          HD        17.0
Fujifilm (blue)     Malaysia            No          HD        16.5
“Scottish HE”       Unknown             No          HD        17.6
“Scottish HE”       Unknown             No          HD        17.5
“Scottish HE”       Unknown             No          HD        17.4
“Scottish HE”       Unknown             No          HD        17.2
“Scottish HE”       Unknown             No          HD        17.4
```

All the disks are NOS, unused, and likely from the same batch from each manufacturer.

Notes:

1. The Fujifilm disks are different colours. It's clear that the pigment/filler used to mould the different coloured cases affects the mass of the disk. Other disks of the same colour from the same box were within 0.1 g of the measured one.
2. The oddly-named "Scottish HE" (HE = Higher Education) brand was sold in various universities and colleges in Scotland. There's no indication of the manufacturer, and packaging was generic.