# Dimension of a 3.5-inch floppy disk

Tags: floppy-disk

Can anyone tell what are the dimensions and/or volume for a 3.5-inch floppy disk?

I am doing a presentation and want to make a visual on how many floppy disks are required to save 200 GB (73662 floppy disks I believe).

Comment: How exactly did you came up with a value of 73662 floppy disks for 200 GB?

Comment: I would assume it has been calculated using the uncommon extended-density format (2880 KiB), but yes, I have been wondering too.

Comment: @Eight-BitGuru 200 binary gigabyte (gibibyte) is 200*1024^3 = 214,748,364,800 bytes. A "1.44" floppy is 1,440 KiB=1,474,560 bytes, so 200 gibibytes is 145,636 floppies. If we take 200 decimal gigabytes, we have 200,000,000,000 bytes, and 135,634 floppies.

Comment: You might want to check this video: https://youtu.be/J-K2yeQylCk

Comment: This might also be a great opportunity to show the picture of Bill Gates showcasing how many sheets of paper fit on a single CD-ROM: https://imgur.com/I5fD3sb

Comment: the imaginary pile of floppies might be helpful for showing the enormous progress we have made, but whatever answer you get, it will be "incorrect" in the sense that nobody at that time would store 200GB of data on floppy disks...

Comment: don't forget to have enough "extra" floppys for error recovery (e.g., via par files) due to the inevitability of loss - dropping a box of them down the stairs, losing them in the warehouse, whatever.

Comment: One little point: Is that 200GB the exact size of the data you want to visualize? After all, it does not make any sense to give a converted value down to the 5th significant digit if the start value is only rounded to the most significant.It would be a beginner error of visualization to state anything more 'exact' than to the 2nd significant - like saying ~74,000 floppies.

Answer (score 18):

A standard 3.5" floppy disk (ANSI X3.137 or ANSI X3.171 size) is physically 90mm x 94mm x 3.3 mm, with a 85.80 mm diameter magnetic disk in the cartridge.

This is the same whether the media is DD, HD or ED inside - so 720k and 2.88M DOS formats are the same physical size.

I believe, but cannot find references to verify this, that the LS-240 media (240 MB disks) was the same physical dimensions as the ANSI standard floppy.

Comment: The wikipedia page for the LS-120 and LS-240 talks about being able to use standard 3.5" disks in the LS- drive, and that the LS- disks expose a fake FAT12 filesystem when put in a standard 3.5" drive. That would imply that they're the same size.

Answer (score 17):

The [ECMA-147](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-147_1st_edition_december_1990.pdf) standard (and, [I am told](https://jdebp.uk/FGA/floppy-discs-are-90mm-not-3-and-a-half-inches.html), the ANSI X3.137 standard too) defines the dimensions of a ‘3.5 inch’ floppy disk as 90 mm × 94 mm × 3.3 mm, which multiplies up to a volume of 27918 mm³ = 27.918 ml (though this is arguably imprecise as it includes the volume of all the notches that, strictly speaking, aren’t part of the floppy disk cassette).

Storing 200 GB of data on floppy disks in probably the most common high-density PC format (1440 KiB each) would require ⌈200 × 1000³ ÷ (1440 × 1024)⌉ = 135 634 floppy disks, so your figure appears to be about two times too small.  But even that doesn’t take into account file system overhead; assuming each floppy contains a FAT12 file system with standard sector reservations (1 boot sector, 14 sectors for directory entries, 2 FATs of 9 sectors each) containing a single file, you end up with ⌈200 × 1000³ ÷ (2847 [sectors] × 512 [bytes per sector])⌉ = 137 206 disks.  If it’s just for illustrative purposes the difference probably doesn’t matter too much, as it’s still roughly the same order of magnitude, but it would be a quite significant one if storing all that data was actually attempted.

Comment: So basically a stack of floppies about as tall as the Petronas Towers (just mere 2.75 tons of them if we go at 20 grams a piece).

Comment: "arguably imprecise as it includes the volume of all the notches" Actually, this is precisely the right way to calculate the volume _in this context._ You can't exactly recover the space used by the notches for packing the floppies tighter, so the dead space needs to be included.

Comment: Excluding the notches is a bit like excluding the internal space between the disk and the corners of the case.

Comment: I was thinking mostly of the cut corner. Perhaps on a large enough scale, that might actually count for something.

Answer (score 4):

Other stats for your 73,662 floppies:

- They would [weigh](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/20097/what-is-the-standardized-weight-of-a-3-5-inch-floppy-disk/24621#24621) roughly 1326 kg. This is about the same as a Mini Cooper S car.
- The labels on their backing paper would cover an area of almost 325 m² (assuming Memorex labels, which came on a 76 × 58 mm sheet): enough to cover the floor of the US White House's Oval Office 4¼ labels deep.
- A roll of labels to label every one would be 4.27 km long (assuming 58 mm per label)
- If packed in boxes of 10 like you got from Memorex, you'd need 7367 boxes, each 94 × 45 × 97 mm. This would cover a standard shipping skid/pallet (1.2 × 1 × 0.162 m) to a height of just over 2.7 m. This wouldn't fit inside a standard sea can / shipping container: they only have a headroom of 2.38 m.

Comment: I'm aware that the boxes of floppies would probably crush if stacked that high on a palette unless packed in outers. I leave that as Somebody Else's Problem